# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 0.6 at line 1 column 8454

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using the retrofit library for my calls in a demo project.

I received the following error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 0.6 at line 1 column 8454 path $.result.results.ads[2].acres

I under stand that this is down to GSON.

I will show you the JSON it's getting caught in:

```
   {  
       "ad_id":739580087654,
       "property_type":"site",
       "house_type":"",
       "selling_type":"private-treaty",
       "price_type":"",
       "agreed":0,
       "priority":2,
       "description":"Beautiful elevated 0.6 acre site - zoned residential - and within easy walk to this popular and scenic coastal village\r\n\r\n\r\nthe site area is zoned residential ( i.e. can be constructed on for residential home) and has beautiful coastal views\r\n\r\nSpiddal is an exceptionally popular location , just 8 miles west of Galway City but the area has not been over developed.\r\n\r\nAll services and family amenities are location in the village centre.\r\n\r\n",
       "price":135000,
       "bedrooms":null,
       "bathrooms":null,
       "tax_section":"0",
       "square_metres":0,
       "acres":0.6,   <----------------------TRIPPING UP HERE
       "features":[  
          "Zoned residential",
          "within easy walk of coastal village of Spiddal",
          "with coastal views"
       ],
       "ber_rating":"",
       "ber_code":"",
       "ber_epi":0,             
       "city":"",
       "general_area":"Connemara",
       "postcode":null,
       "latlon_accuracy":1,
       "main_email":"",
       "cc_email":"",
       "auction_address":"",
       "start_date":1384425002,
       "listing_date":1384425002,
       "agreed_date":0,
       "auction_date":0,
       "tags":1
    },
```

I'm not that experienced with Retrofit so decided to learn and integrate on this project.

Would anyone have any suggestions?

**I don't have any control over the JSON being sent down.**

Comment: Use a `float` instead of and `int`.

Comment: in my response object?  Will this not cause issues where there are ints?

Comment: In the actual (java) code.

Comment: that's what I was referring to, in java code in my response object

Comment: @TheCoffeeKid thank you, that worked

Comment: Would you like me to post that as an answer?

Comment: @TheCoffeeKid if you post as an answer I'll accept, thank you

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try using a `float` or `double` instead of an `int`; `0.6` is not an integer, it is a decimal. Note that java automatically interprets decimals as `doubles`; an example of a float would be `0.6f`.

Comment: I was looking for the error in the retrofit call code, but it was in the data object, as you point out. Simple and helpful

Answer (score 2):

That's because the parser is expecting an `int` whereas the actual value it got was `float`. What you can do is, change that value's type from `int` to `float` in your model.

This might cause problems in your code wherever you are using that value. You can solve it by casting that float value to an integer.