# Parsing Integer primitive types in Realm

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

Want to parse this JSON response in Realm but it always crashes for the categories:

```
[
  {
    "id": 32,
    "name": "ABC",
    "height": "49.5000",
    "categories": [
      14,15,16
    ]
  }
]
```

### Info.java:

```
public class Info extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer height;
    private RealmList<RealmInt> categories;
}
```

### RealmInt.java

```
public class RealmInt extends RealmObject{
    private Integer val;

    public RealmInt() {

    }

    public RealmInt(Integer val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public Integer getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

### This is how I parse when I receiving this JSON:

```
String stringBody = response.body().string();
List<Info> newObjects = GsonIntWrapper.intBuilder().fromJson(stringBody, new TypeToken<List<Info>>(){}.getType());
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newObjects);
```

### GsonIntWrapper.intBuilder()

public class GsonIntWrapper {

```
public static Gson intBuilder(){
    Type tokenInt = new TypeToken<RealmList<RealmInt>>(){}.getType();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .registerTypeAdapter(tokenInt, new TypeAdapter<RealmList<RealmInt>>() {

                @Override
                public void write(JsonWriter out, RealmList<RealmInt> value) throws IOException {
                    // Ignore
                }

                @Override
                public RealmList<RealmInt> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                    RealmList<RealmInt> list = new RealmList<RealmInt>();
                    in.beginArray();
                    while (in.hasNext()) {
                        list.add(new RealmInt(in.nextInt()));
                    }
                    in.endArray();
                    return list;
                }
            })
            .create();
    return gson;
  }
}
```

### The crash Log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 49.5000 at line 1 column 18581 path $[4].height
```

Comment: Add the crash log please

Comment: Hey @Tim, just added the meaningful crash lines at the bottom of the question. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Why is `height` an `Integer` if you want to set its value to `49.5000`?

Comment: Looks plain to me, you have a double/float where it requires an int

Comment: @Hey Micheal, height is a number, and correct me if I am wrong, for Realm we don't have floats or decimal but I believe and we use generic type Integer??

Comment: [Supported fields](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/3187/realm/10895/realm-models) are boolean, byte, short, int, long, **float, double**, String, Date, byte[], links to other RealmObjects, and RealmList<T extends RealmModel>.

Comment: Guys, I did change the data type to float and now everything seems good. Thank you all awesome members for your precious time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log says it all , the variable "height" on your json is not an int modify the model like this :

```
public class Info extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Double height;
    private RealmList<RealmInt> categories;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, it was my bad :) Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

In your Json value "height"  is **float** but in your RealmObject class (Info) is **int**

You can see this link it's a similar issue [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095497/java-lang-numberformatexception-expected-an-int-but-was-0-6-at-line-1-column-84)

Comment: Thanks as your answer meant the same .